# when sent the mail it shows an error like,AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

when sent the mail it shows an error like,AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines',can slove this issue

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from random import randint
def send_emails(request,email):
n = 8
range_start = 10**(n-1)
range_end = (10**n)-1
passgenarate = randint(range_start, range_end)
print passgenarate
password = make_password(passgenarate)
print password

updatepassword =  User.objects.filter(email=email).update(password=password)
subject = 'newpassword'
from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
recipient_list = email
message = passgenarate
send_mail(subject, message,from_email,[recipient_list],
          fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None,
          connection=None, html_message=None)
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `message = passgenarate` needs to be a `str` and it's an `int`. Try `message = str(passgenarate)`.